# Unable to install amdgpu drivers for ubuntu 18.04 RX 560X

Tags: opencl, ubuntu-18.04, amd-gpu

I purchased an Acer Nitro Ryzen 5 laptop with Radeon RX 560X GPU mainly for some GPU computing tasks with OpenCL. However, I am unable to install the drivers from AMD's website which are available for Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is the config:

```
$ sudo lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
 01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
 Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] [1002:67ef] (rev c0)
 04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]       [1002:15dd] (rev c4)
```

I downloaded the drivers from AMD's website. There is a similar thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107272/installing-amdgpu-18-50-for-ubuntu-18-04-resulting-in-dependency-issues). But no solution is given. Now I am also facing the same unmet dependencies issue discussed in the link given. How can I go about using OpenCL with TensorFlow now?

Ok i have installed the drivers successfully including the ones for opencl. But now when i run clinfo in terminal it is showing ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs(-1001)

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].